# What are entry.php and its appendix files and is it safe to delete them in a most miniaml site?

Tags: theme-development

Regarding the entry.php and it's appendix files, which are, as I understand:

```
entry-content.php
entry-summary.php
entry-footer.php
entry-meta.php
```

Say I create a small website and create it with a page builder and desire only these templates and aspects, and nothing more:

```
index.php, header.php,footer.php, functions.php, search.php
style.css, behavior.js
page.php, single.php
category.php, tag.php, author.php, comments.php
```

Whould I still need entry.php and it's appendixes? Is it safe to delete them for a more minimal workflow if I aim to create a theme aimed for creating a small page-builder oriented site?

Comment: The only files a theme is truly required to have are `style.css` and `index.php`. From there you only need to create what you will use. So, yes, it is safe to create a theme without the additional files you've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

These **entry** files are not standard WP templates, and theme uses them most likely to render only loop content. Some themes name these files **loop** and some **content**.

It is a good idea to have loop content in separate files for easier reuse. Check out default WP themes to learn more about what templates are comonly used, and what files are extra. Check out the official [Templates Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).